# How to Turn on the Windows Location platform in windows 8 using powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to check the option for "Turn on the Windows Location platform" in windows 8 using PowerShell? 
This option is available under control panel - Location Settings.

I haven't find any registry setting made for this once when I turn it on manually. If I find any registry setting I could have used that registry option to enable it but unfortunately there is no change in registry.

thanks in advance
Praveen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I just used Procmon to see which reg key was being changed and see the key is named  'SensorPermissionState'. If the checkbox is checked (i.e. it's turned on) then the value is 1.

If you clear the checkbox it gets set to 0x00000000

So this should turn it on (seems to require you to be in Admin Shell):

```
Set-ItemProperty ` 
    -path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Sensor\Overrides\{BFA794E4-F964-4FDB-90F6-51056BFE4B44}\' ` 
    -name sensorpermissionstate -value 1
```

And to turn it off

```
Set-ItemProperty ` 
    -path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows nt\CurrentVersion\Sensor\Overrides\{BFA794E4-F964-4FDB-90F6-51056BFE4B44}' `
    -name sensorpermissionstate -Value 0
```